# "Let's separate the wheat from the chaff"

Tags: meaning, phrases

If you were sending an invite for a weekly workout challenge at the end of which there would be winners, would you be able to use this phrase?

If you did, could it sound rude?

Is this a British, an American or an internationally accepted phrase?

Thank you!

Comment: It does sound rude: chaff is [worthless, or trash.](https://www.google.com/search?q=chaff&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=MeFxWZ_GEazLXvX2uYAN)

Comment: Probably best to use something motivational, rather than depressing (for those that didn't make it)

Comment: Judging by the community's acceptance of this idiom over "separate the men from the boys" it seems that "separate the wheat from the chaff" is **less** offensive, relatively speaking...https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377460/how-to-degender-separate-the-men-from-the-boys

Comment: @thomj1332 only on a gender-neutrality basis.

Comment: I think it could be used humorously, however only if you're comfortable with that type of jocular humor and would be willing to say something like "winners from the losers" or "men from the boys" or "Pros from the scrubs". Guys commonly joked around that way among themselves, although with the changes in social mores about always being supportive, that sort of teasing and playful boasting probably isn't as common anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*Separating the wheat from the chaff*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/separate-wheat-from-chaff) suggests that the process - whatever it is - is going to separate that which is useful (the wheat) from that which is useless (the chaff). If used in a context like you suggest, it would imply that the non-winners are useless - essentially insulting them for not being 'the best' in whatever way your 'workout challenge' defines. Don't use this phrase for this purpose.

Comment: Are you aware that the link goes to a 'no results' page?

Comment: @Spagirl - It works for me.

Comment: Something else to consider is that this is a biblical reference to the parable in Matthew 3:12 where John the Baptist is talking about the one to come after him. It's a general usage phrase/cliche generally, but it's just about conceivable that some audiences may be discomfited. Same would apply to 'sheep from goats' and wheat from tares'.

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/separate-wheat-from-chaff Maybe it's a browser issue, I'm on a phone right now.

Comment: That's weird, just tried on pic and its fine, on safari the search puts dashes between the words!

Comment: @Spagirl - the link *does* have dashes between the words.

Comment: When I follow the link in Chrome on a PC, it works: taking me to results for 'separate wheat from chaff', with no dashes.  When i follow it on my phone, either in Chrome or Safari, it returns a 'no results' page for 'separate-wheat-from-chaff', *with* dashes. So it looks like a mobile phone glitch rather than a problem with your link.

Comment: @Spagirl - looks that way; Chrome on my Android tablet works just fine...